# Filter array of objects inside objects in typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am trying to filter my object with an array of objects inside. Currently, I have this data.

```
 {
  tile: "test title",
  id: 1,
  createdBy: "johndoe@example.com",
  comments: "",
  taskId: "TK-12345",
  schedules: [
    {
      id: 101,
      dateAssigned: "2019-10,-03",
      taskStatus: "On track"
    },
    {
      id: 102,
      dateAssigned: "2019-10,-03",
      taskStatus: "On track"
    }
  ]
},
{
  tile: "test title no. 2",
  id: 1,
  createdBy: "johndoe@example.com",
  comments: "",
  taskId: "TK-54321",
  schedules: [
    {
      id: 101,
      dateAssigned: "2019-09,-03",
      taskStatus: "Overdue"
    }
  ]
},
{
  tile: "test title no. 3",
  id: 1,
  createdBy: "johndoe@example.com",
  comments: "",
  taskId: "TK-99999",
  schedules: [
    {
      id: 103,
      dateAssigned: "2019-09,-03",
      taskStatus: "Open"
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to filter only *"Open"* and *"Overdue"* items.

```
this.urgentRequests = this.urgentRequests.filter(a => {
   return a.schedules.find(s => s.taskStatus !== 'On track');
});
```

Currently, it is not working. It is possible to filter and find at the same time?

I am still getting *'On track'* items
[image]

The expected output gets only data with overdue and open items.
But right now its is returning all items including *"On track"*

```
{
  tile: "test title no. 2",
  id: 1,
  createdBy: "johndoe@example.com",
  comments: "",
  taskId: "TK-54321",
  schedules: [
    {
      id: 101,
      dateAssigned: "2019-09,-03",
      status: "Overdue"
    }
  ]
},
{
  tile: "test title no. 3",
  id: 1,
  createdBy: "johndoe@example.com",
  comments: "",
  taskId: "TK-99999",
  schedules: [
    {
      id: 103,
      dateAssigned: "2019-09,-03",
      status: "Open"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Sorry not to include that in the question i'll update the question.

Comment: What if no 3 has both an “Open” and a “on Track”, should it be returned in the output?

Comment: Based on the current requirements it would not happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were on the right track, but your outer arrow function was missing a `return` and you should use `some` instead of `find`. You need to use `return` if your arrow function has braces around the body; I fixed this by dropping the braces. Also, you wrote `taskStatus` instead of `status`.

```
this.urgentRequests.filter(a =>
    a.schedules.some(s => s.status !== 'On track'))
```

Comment: my mistake I input the wrong key it should be 'taskStatus' not 'status'. However I tried this one but it is still returning items with 'On track' status.

Comment: It works for me on the input you gave. Please give an example of where it fails.

Comment: Thanks. Its working now i just missed a closing parenthesis.

Answer (score 2):

Using `Array.prototype.reduce`, you can extract filtered items only.

```js
const input = [{
  tile: "test title",
  id: 1,
  createdBy: "johndoe@example.com",
  comments: "",
  taskId: "TK-12345",
  schedules: [
    {
      id: 101,
      dateAssigned: "2019-10,-03",
      status: "On track"
    },
    {
      id: 102,
      dateAssigned: "2019-10,-03",
      status: "On track"
    }
  ]
},
{
  tile: "test title no. 2",
  id: 1,
  createdBy: "johndoe@example.com",
  comments: "",
  taskId: "TK-54321",
  schedules: [
    {
      id: 101,
      dateAssigned: "2019-09,-03",
      status: "Overdue"
    }
  ]
},
{
  tile: "test title no. 3",
  id: 1,
  createdBy: "johndoe@example.com",
  comments: "",
  taskId: "TK-99999",
  schedules: [
    {
      id: 103,
      dateAssigned: "2019-09,-03",
      status: "Open"
    }
  ]
}];

const output = input.reduce((acc, cur) => {
  const schedules = cur.schedules.filter(({status}) => status === 'Open' || status === 'Overdue');
  if (schedules.length > 0) {
    acc.push({
      ...cur,
      schedules
    });
  }
  return acc;
}, []);
console.log(output);
```

Comment: Why not just check for not “On Track” on the some?

Comment: `I want to filter only "Open" and "Overdue" items.` It's on question.

Answer (score 1):

I think your code is almost correct,

```
// Your code
this.urgentRequests = this.urgentRequests.filter(a => {
  a.schedules.find(s => s.taskStatus !== 'On track');
});
```

1. Change the `s.taskStatus` into `s.status` instead. If you look closely, the key name is `status`.
2. Use a return statement. `filter` expects a function that return boolean as the input. In your case, your function not returning anything, thus returning undefined (computed to false).

So, the code should looks like this:

```
this.urgentRequests = this.urgentRequests.filter(a => {
  return a.schedules.find(s => s.status !== 'On track');
});
```

Edit: I added code snippet to make sure everything is working. And it does. You can check it below.

```js
const items = [{
  tile: "test title",
  id: 1,
  createdBy: "johndoe@example.com",
  comments: "",
  taskId: "TK-12345",
  schedules: [
    {
      id: 101,
      dateAssigned: "2019-10,-03",
      status: "On track"
    },
    {
      id: 102,
      dateAssigned: "2019-10,-03",
      status: "On track"
    }
  ]
},
{
  tile: "test title no. 2",
  id: 1,
  createdBy: "johndoe@example.com",
  comments: "",
  taskId: "TK-54321",
  schedules: [
    {
      id: 101,
      dateAssigned: "2019-09,-03",
      status: "Overdue"
    }
  ]
},
{
  tile: "test title no. 3",
  id: 1,
  createdBy: "johndoe@example.com",
  comments: "",
  taskId: "TK-99999",
  schedules: [
    {
      id: 103,
      dateAssigned: "2019-09,-03",
      status: "Open"
    }
  ]
}]

const targets = ["open", "overdue"];

const filterResult = items.filter(item => {
    return item.schedules.find(s => targets.includes(s.status.toLowerCase()))
})

console.log("I named the original array into 'items'.");
console.log("I add toLowerCase to make sure it wasn't typing issue.");
console.log("The results are: ", filterResult);
console.log("The result's schedules are: ", filterResult.map(a => a.schedules));
console.log(" No more 'On Track' right :) ");
```

NB: I'm using several new techniques but the idea is still the same.

Comment: my mistake I input the wrong key it should be 'taskStatus' not 'status'. However I tried this one but it is still returning items with 'On track' status.

Comment: Hmm, how could? I tried the same code with the same input and it worked. Maybe it's something outside of the code?

Comment: I'm currently checking it. Maybe it is. I'll get back when it's done. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you its working now. I just missed a parenthesis. However i use Brian's answer.